# How to generate Joint Normal Probability Distribution of randomly Weights and Heights

Tags: statistics, probability

I'm doing this by multiplying mode and sigma of weight with height and then by using numpy get the generated distribution but still this is not correct as I want to have Histogram of Weight on the X-axis and Height on the Y-axis.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Post the code you are using now, and the results you are getting.

Comment: Let S be a covariance matrix, e.g. covariance of height and weight. Let L . transpose(L) be a Cholesky decomposition of S, that is S = L . transpose(L), where L is a lower triangular matrix. Then the covariance of L . X is S where X is a vector of independent Gaussian variables with zero mean and unit variance. In summary, compute Cholesky decomposition of your covariance and multiply independent Gaussian (0, 1) variables by that in order to get a sample from a distribution which has your covariance.